# Angular 6 + Codeigniter same port

Tags: angular, codeigniter-3, .htaccess

I have an Angular 6 project; and in a subdirectory of the root is the server with a CodeIgniter (/api).

Having a redirection configuration of 404 to the home of the web; I can enter the index path of the api (/api/index.php) but any path that delves into the api, redirects me to the home of the web.

I would like to know; how can I tell Angular Routing NOT to control that route (/api), or the reason for the erroneous redirection.

*app.routes.ts*

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', redirectTo: 'home',pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'pages', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'store', redirectTo: 'pagesstore', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

*.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take away the wildcard route

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

You'll be able to access a Codeigniter view.

Comment: It might work, but the problem is that I would lose the security of knowing that the 404 is redirected correctly. 

Wouldn't a better way to tell routing that a certain route doesn't control it? Is that possible?

Comment: Security wise, Angular won't do anything against accessing certain pages since all the code lives on the client and can be hacked easy. Your backend has to hold security against data.... if you want a 404 page, I would do it with .htaccess instead of the wildcard in your case.

Comment: Not sure there's a way to tell Angular not to handle routes if the wildcard is present